# batch file to copy files to specified folders

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that receives 1 to 9 files (or more) and it needs to copy those files to a set of folders. Can anyone help me out?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do (
   copy %%i "\Folder1"
   copy %%i "\Folder3"
   copy %%i "\Folder5"
....
)
```

Copy file1 passed as parameter %1 to all the destination folders, then file2 from %2 and so on...
But I don't know what to write instead of %%1 in the do () procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although LotPings' answer will work, a simpler answer, which is closer to the attempt in the original question and avoids the ungainly `goto`, would be:-

```
for %%i in (%*) do (
   copy %%i "\Folder1"
   copy %%i "\Folder3"
   copy %%i "\Folder5"
....
)
```

Here `%*` expands to the full parameter list, however long it is, and the `for` statement takes account of any quotes, stepping in turn through each parameter as given. Again there is no restriction to 9 parameters, though batch files are subject to an overall maximum of 255 parameters.

Answer (score 2):

To not be restricted to 9 arguments I'd use a loop with a goto and [shift](http://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) until no arguments left.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\23\SU_1377880.cmd
@Echo off
:loop
if "%~1"=="" goto :Eof
if exist "%~1" (
    copy %1 "\Folder1"
    copy %1 "\Folder3"
    copy %1 "\Folder5"
) else ( Echo %1 not found )
shift
goto :loop
```